# I can't get onCellValueChanged event called

Tags: ag-grid-angular

I'm testing ag-grid on angular 7. One of the things I want to do is detect cell changes in the grid, but I can't get the onCellValueChanged() fired. I'm just making my first steps in js and angular so maybe this is a silly question. Thanks

My grid definition in app.component.html:

```
<ag-grid-angular style="width: 950px; height: 320px;" class="ag-theme-balham" 
    [enableSorting]="true" [enableFilter]="true"
    [rowData]="stocks" [columnDefs]="columnDefs" rowSelection="multiple"
    [enterMovesDownAfterEdit]="true"
    [enterMovesDown]="true">
    (cellValueChanged)="onCellValueChanged($event)"
</ag-grid-angular>
```

My app.component.ts:

```
import { Component , OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { StockService } from './stock.service';
import { stock } from './stock';
import {MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'app';
    stocks: stock[];
    public loading = false;
    pedidos: stock[];

    constructor(private stockService: StockService) {this.stocks = []; }

    columnDefs = [
    {headerName: 'Código',
        field: 'cod_ins',
        width: 150,
        suppressSizeToFit: true
        },
    {headerName: 'Cantidad',
        field: 'pedido',
        width: 110,
        editable: true,
        type: 'numericColumn',
     }

    ];


  onCellValueChanged(params: any) {

    console.log('Estoy en onCellValueChanged !!!');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Uh, the problem was that the > was in the wrong place:

```
[enterMovesDown]="true">
(cellValueChanged)="onCellValueChanged($event)"
```

It should be here:

```
[enterMovesDown]="true"
(cellValueChanged)="onCellValueChanged($event)">
```

No error emitted by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because rowData is not changing (this.stocks = [] - alwasy, but it should be changed if you want detect it in onCellValueChanged() method)
Try to use:

```
@Input() stocks
```

or try to get stock from the server survey by polling